# Short circuit evaluation with both && || operator

Tags: c, short-circuiting

I know what is short circuit evaluation in C.

`a && b` (operand b is not checked if a = 0)

`a || b` (operand b is not checked if a = non zero)

But I am stuck at this question

```
int x = 0;
if (5 || 2 && ++x)
    printf("%d", x);
```

This outputs `0`.

My first thinking goes as follows:

According to precedence table , precedence is `++`, `&&`, `||` (descending order)

1. `++x`: `evaluated.x` becomes 1.
2. `2 && ++x` evaluated. Both operands are evaluated.
3. `||` is evaluated.

But according to this, `1` should be printed, not `0`.

My second thinking goes as this:

```
5 || anything
```

`anything` is not evaluated because of short circuit evaluation, so no precedence comes into play here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `5 || 2 && ++x` is equivalent to `5 || (2 && ++x)` due to operator precedence.

The run time evaluates the expression `5 || 2 && ++x` from left to right.

As we know in **OR** if first condition is true it will not check the second condition.
So here 5 evaluated as true and so `(2 && ++x)`  will not be performed.

That's why x will remain 0 here.

Answer (score 2):

Correct. The expression is short circuited. You can test it with this.

```
if(5 || ++x) {
  printf("%d\n",x);
}
```